# How to insert data using spring mvc and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I want to insert data into database by using AngularJS and spring mvc, according to tutorial i did everything but i failed to insert data into database.

controller :

```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
          public @ResponseBody String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute(value="employee")EmployeeEntity employee, BindingResult result) 
{
    employeeManager.addEmployee(employee);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

jsCode :

```
  $scope.insertData = function(){
    $http.post("http://localhost:9090/CrudOperations/add", {"firstname":$scope.firstname})
    .success(function(data,status,header,config)
            {

                console.log("inserted");
            });

}
```

jsp:

```
   <form:form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post"  commandName="employee">

<div class="form-group col-lg-7" >
  <label for="email" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Firstname"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-7">
   <button type="submit" ng-click="insertData()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use browser dev tools network tab to inspect actual request. First place to start when debugging ajax after verifying no exceptions thrown in console. Need status, check what was sent/returned etc. Need to narrow down if problem is client side or server side this way

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify exactly what your problem is and what behaviour you are experiencing, but there seems to be some problems with your code that can be pointed out.

It seems like you are trying to mix two ways of communicating with your backend - more traditional, form based approach, and a Rest API.

Annotating your controller method with @ResponseBody means, that Spring should not try to resolve a view to render. It should instead convert the object that has been returned from your method using a message converter (usually - serialize it to JSON) and send the result back to the client in the response body. This is used to expose a Rest endpoint.

That means that returning the String "redirect:/" will not cause a redirect. 
Instead the String will be returned in the body.

It would probably be better to return the persisted entity that probably is returned by `employeeManager.addEmployee(employee)` if the process of persisting it causes its id to be set. This way the client can receive that id and find the employee later.

If you are passing your data from Angular to the backend using JSON you should probably also use @RequestBody annotation instead of @ModelAttribute. This in turn will cause the object to be deserialized. You did not show your EmployeeEntity class, so I don't know if that is what you want.

On the client side you probably don't need the form element. Angular can pass data using AJAX calls. Having the form and a submit button will cause your browser to reload the page and that is not what you usually want if you are creating a single page application.